# Заполнение таблиц в Android

Tags: java, android

Заполняю таблицу из трёх столбцов. Данные правильно распределяются по столбцам только для первого совпадения, второе и все остальные совпадения складываются в первый столбец. Помогите исправить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private TableLayout TblLay;
private TableRow TblRow;
private TextView tmc, inv, sn;

            TblLay = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbllayout);
            TblLay.setStretchAllColumns(true);
            TblLay.setShrinkAllColumns(true);

            tmc = findViewById(R.id.tmc);
            inv = findViewById(R.id.invid);
            sn = findViewById(R.id.sn);

            Elements elements = doc.select("input[name=text]");
            for (int j = 0; j < elements.size(); j++) {
                Element txt = elements.get(j);
                String text = txt.attr("value");
                tmc.setText(text);
                tmc = new TextView(MyThngsTblActivity.this);
                TblLay.addView(tmc);

                Elements select = doc.select("input[name=invid]");
                for (int i = j; i <= j; i++) {
                    Element invs = select.get(i);
                    String invid = invs.attr("value");
                    inv.setText(invid);
                    inv = new TextView(MyThngsTblActivity.this);
                    TblLay.addView(inv);

                    Elements select1 = doc.select("input[name=sn]");
                    for (int k = i; k <= i; k++) {
                        Element snss = select1.get(k);
                        String sns = snss.attr("value");
                        sn.setText(sns);
                        sn = new TextView(MyThngsTblActivity.this);
                        TblLay.addView(sn);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Вы все данные добавляете в заголовок таблицы. Т.е. нет в коде добавления строки таблицы. И использовать вложенные циклы очень плохая практика! Зачем они нужны? В третьем цикле перебираете `k` а используете `get(i)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласен, что вложенные циклы не очень способ, но для небольшого объёма данных сойдёт.

```
            Elements elements = doc.select("input[name=text]");
            for (int j = 0; j < elements.size(); j++) {
                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(MyThngsTblActivity.this);
                Element txt = elements.get(j);
                String text = txt.attr("value");
                tmc.setText(text);
                tmc = new TextView(MyThngsTblActivity.this);
                tableRow.addView(tmc);
                TblLay.addView(tableRow);

                Elements select = doc.select("input[name=invid]");
                TableRow tableRow2 = new TableRow(MyThngsTblActivity.this);
                for (int i = j; i <= j; i++) {
                    Element invs = select.get(i);
                    String invid = invs.attr("value");
                    inv.setText(invid);
                    inv = new TextView(MyThngsTblActivity.this);
                    tableRow.addView(inv);
                    TblLay.addView(tableRow2);

                    Elements select1 = doc.select("input[name=sn]");
                    for (int k = i; k <= i; k++) {
                        TableRow tableRow3 = new TableRow(MyThngsTblActivity.this);
                        Element snss = select1.get(k);
                        String sns = snss.attr("value");
                        sn.setText(sns);
                        sn = new TextView(MyThngsTblActivity.this);
                        tableRow.addView(sn);
                        TblLay.addView(tableRow3);
                    }
                }
            }
```